# Using a different manifestPlaceholder for nested Flavors

Tags: android, build-variant

I do have a structure like below. I wanna use different manifestPlaceHolder like this, projectXTest, projectXDev, projectXProd all use different manifestPlaceHolder while projectYTest,Prod,Dev uses the same manifestPlaceHolder. What I can do besides putting that values to string.xml for all different flavors

```
android {
    buildTypes{
        debug{
            // Some debug setup
        }
        release{
            // Some release setup
        }
    }


   flavorDimensions "project" , "default"
    productFlavors {
        projectX{
         dimension 'project'
           }
       
        projectY{
          dimension 'project'
           }

        Test{
          dimension 'default'
           }
        Dev{
          dimension 'default'
           }
        Prod{
          dimension 'default'
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I could find an out of this. I followed this steps. I hope, If somebody find her/himself in this situation, this helps.

**Firstly**

Put a manifest to desired flavors directory, for my example I've put android manifest to src/projectY and src/projectX

Beware these not to be full manifest. It should be layered like below

```
<manifest>
  <application>
    <activity>
        android:name=".x.loginActivity"
        tools:node="merge" // this is must
        // your flavor spesific code
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**Secondly**

Delete your code to minimum in main XML. What i mean that manifest you've created in src/flavor will be merged with main one. so that delete what you want to seperate and leave what you want to used common in main.

**Thirdly**

Give different manifestPlaceholder name  if you need to seperate prod,dev and staging.
For example,

src/projectX/manifest.xml

```
 <activity>
    .
    .
    android:host='${projectXHost}'
    .
    </activity>
```

src/projectY/manifest.xml

```
<activity>
.
.
android:host='${projectYHost}'
.
</activity>
```

in gradle

```
productFlavors{

 prod {
   manifestPlaceholders = [projectXHost : 'xxx' , projectYHost : 'yyy']
}

}
```

Since this is my first answer, I'm sorry with layout and expressions. I hope you can understand what I mean. Have a good day